# tf.test.is_gpu_available() return false

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My tensonflow version is 2.3.0, Cuda is 10.1 and 10.0. I have different version cudnn for each cuda 10.1 and 10.0.
I set up path like this:[path for cuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrdMY.jpg)

when I run code in CMD like this:

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: tf.test.is_gpu_available()
2021-01-12 20:06:38.461001: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
Out[2]: False
```

I tired two version of cuda. it always return false to me. what is happening here and how can make it return true?
Thanks!

Comment: `Tensorflow-2.3.0` requires python `3.5-3.8` and with `GCC 7.3.1` and `Bazel 3.1.0` `CUDNN 7.6` and `CUDA 10.1` Do you have these versions? @pengfei yao

Comment: Thanks papaya! I found some information about tensorflow. https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/12/whats-new-in-tensorflow-24.html

Comment: It says tensorflow 2.4 could enable to run with cuda 11.1 and cudnn 8.X. I just update tensorflow version from 2.3 to 2.4 and cuda verstion 11.1 and cudnn 8. it is still not able to find gpu.

Comment: Do you have nvidia-smi installed & what happens when you type that?

Answer (score 1):

On windows Os, Tensorflow-GPU setup, follow these steps

Add the CUDA®, CUPTI, and cuDNN installation directories to the %PATH% environmental variable. For example, if the CUDA® Toolkit is installed to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1 and cuDNN to C:\tools\cuda, update your %PATH% to match:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had struggles in the set up of the environment to allow Tensorflow to see my GPU.
First of all you should check [this table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu):

Then the road split:

- if you have Anaconda I suggest you to create a new environment and fresh install tensorflow-gpu. Here it is a [good guide](https://shawnhymel.com/1961/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-windows/)
- if you don't use Anaconda you will have to install all the packages via the pip command. Looking at table that I previously linked, I provide you an example:

  ```
   pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0
   pip install cudnn==7.6.0
   pip install cudatoolkit==10.1
  ```

Be careful to match the correct Python version and if your GPU is actually supported when you install a specific version of Tensorflow.